# How to convert values like Decimal('0.303440') in list to float in Python Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, list, decimal

I have list in Python like below:

```
    my_list = [[Decimal('0.303440'), 0.0, 2.0, 8.0, 1.0],
 [109.0, 10.0, 0.0, 0.0, 3.0],
 [52.0, 5.0, 99.0, 0.0, Decimal('0.445378')]]
```

- As you can se most of values is float, but some values are like: `Decimal('0.303440')`
- How can I transform all values in my list like: Decimal('0.303440') to float like: 0.303440.
- Of course in my real list I have many mores values like: `Decimal('0.303440')` and we have to
  use full automation because I can't write them out manually.

So, as a result I need something like below:

```
    my_list = [[0.303440, 0.0, 2.0, 8.0, 1.0],
 [109.0, 10.0, 0.0, 0.0, 3.0],
 [52.0, 5.0, 99.0, 0.0, 0.445378]]
```

How can I do that in Python Pandas ?

Comment: I'm curious to know how they got there.

Comment: `[list(map(float, l)) for l in my_list]` would be a simple start…?!

Comment: You have a straightforward Python list (of lists). You don't need pandas for this

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use:

```
df = df.map(float)
```

***[CODE DEMO](https://replit.com/@msankrit/SweetPerfumedSale#main.py)***

Comment: mandy8055, using your code I have error: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'applymap'

Comment: Note: applymap deprecated in latest Pandas - can use map() instead